# How is KL-divergence in pytorch code related to the formula?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, autoencoder

In VAE tutorial, kl-divergence of two Normal Distributions is defined by:
[image]

And in many code, such as [here](https://github.com/timbmg/Sentence-VAE/blob/master/train.py), [here](https://github.com/timbmg/VAE-CVAE-MNIST/blob/master/train.py#L35)and [here](https://github.com/Statham-stone/pytorch-vae/blob/master/vae.py), the code is implemented as:

```
 KL_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logv - mean.pow(2) - logv.exp())
```

or

```
def latent_loss(z_mean, z_stddev):
    mean_sq = z_mean * z_mean
    stddev_sq = z_stddev * z_stddev
    return 0.5 * torch.mean(mean_sq + stddev_sq - torch.log(stddev_sq) - 1)
```

How are they related? why there is not any "tr" or ".transpose()" in code?

Comment: This is worked out in the original VAE paper by Kingma ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf)) in appendix B. Note that there's an additional scaling in the second version which uses `torch.mean` instead of `torch.sum` which isn't a problem since scaling doesn't change the optimal points (though it may mean you need a different learning rate).

Comment: @jodag very helpful, thanks

Comment: @jodag About torch.sum and torch.mean, you said "it may mean you need a different learning rate", but the KL loss is not the only loss term, loss=kl_loss+recon_loss, does that mean the loss is actually a weighted sum with different weights?

Comment: Yes if you use mean instead of sum then the kl_loss component will implicitly be weighted less than the original formulation which may have an impact on the optimal points of the loss function and may affect the final result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expressions in the code you posted assume X is an **uncorrelated** multi-variate Gaussian random variable. This is apparent by the lack of cross terms in the determinant of the covariance matrix. Therefore the mean vector and covariance matrix take the forms

[image]

Using this we can quickly derive the following equivalent representations for the components of the original expression

[image]

Substituting these back into the original expression gives

[image]

Comment: Is the final expression valid if sigma and  mu come from distributions other than Gaussian?

Comment: @muammar This expression assumes that the entries in X are drawn i.i.d. from a Gaussian distribution. I doubt the expression would be valid if X were drawn from a different distribution since KL divergence is a function of the distribution and not just the first and second moments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jodag, that makes everything clearer to me --especially the `KL divergence is a function of the distribution and not just the first and second moments`.