# KL Divergence loss Equation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I had a quick question regarding the KL divergence loss as while I'm researching I have seen numerous different implementations. The two most commmon are these two. However, while look at the mathematical equation, I'm not sure if mean should be included.

```
KL_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + torch.log(sigma**2) - mean**2 - sigma**2)

OR 

KL_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + torch.log(sigma**2) - mean**2 - sigma**2)
KL_loss = torch.mean(KL_loss)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get that implementation from? I've never seen it before, what are sigma and mean in this context?

Comment: @JayMody some examples I looked are at . https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/how-is-this-pytorch-expression-equivalent-to-the-kl-divergence

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597340/how-is-kl-divergence-in-pytorch-code-related-to-the-formula

In the second link there are 3 github links that have those implementations as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation being used here calculates the loss for a **single example**:

[image]

For batches of data, we need to calculate the loss over **multiple examples**.

Using our per example equation, we get multiple loss values, 1 per example. We need some way to reduce the per example loss calculations to a single scalar value. Most commonly, you want to take the mean over the batch. You'll see that most of [pytorch's loss functions](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) use `reduction="mean"`. The advantage of taking the mean instead of the sum is that our loss becomes batch size invariant (i.e. doesn't scale with batch size).

From the [stackoverflow post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597340/how-is-kl-divergence-in-pytorch-code-related-to-the-formula) with the implementations, you'll see the [first](https://github.com/timbmg/Sentence-VAE/blob/05b9b65aee81fb2b60a50fa388c4ec4c7959b320/train.py#L128) and [second](https://github.com/timbmg/VAE-CVAE-MNIST/blob/17999593217f29072c6685992afed3f40c6ca5f8/train.py#L37) linked implementations take the mean over the batch (i.e. divide by the batch size).

```py
KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + log_var - mean.pow(2) - log_var.exp())
...
(BCE + KLD) / x.size(0)
```

```py
KL_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logv - mean.pow(2) - logv.exp())
...
(NLL_loss + KL_weight * KL_loss) / batch_size
```

The [third](https://github.com/statham-stone/pytorch-vae/blob/a0d0c2d36507eb4ce9d99ae1dd173b29693fd0e4/vae.py#L81) linked implementation takes the mean over not just the batch, but also the sigma/mu vectors themselves:

```py
0.5 * torch.mean(mean_sq + stddev_sq - torch.log(stddev_sq) - 1)
```

So instead of scaling the sum by `1/N` where `N` is the batch size, you're scaling by `1/(NM)` where `M` is the dimensionality of the `mu` and `sigma` vectors. In this case, your loss is both batch size and latent dimension size invariant. It's important to note that scaling your loss doesn't change the *"shape"* of the loss landscape (i.e. optimal points stay fixed), it just scales it (which you can control how to step through via the learning rate).

Comment: Thank you so much!

I just want to make sure I understand correctly. I'm training over images and each loop is a batch of 128 images. and the loss function is calculated for every image. So basically my kl loss should be the following:

kl_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + std - mu_sqaured - std.exp())/mu.shape[0]

I also want to point out when I used

kl_loss = -0.5 * torch.mean(1 + std - mu_sqaured - std.exp()) instead of kl_loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + std - mu_sqaured - std.exp()). The results were drastically better

Comment: I think probably the best thing to do is just use: `-0.5 * torch.mean(1 + std - mu_sqaured - std.exp())` (no division by batch size, since it's included in the `torch.mean`). This way your loss is both batch size and latent size invariant, and you can tune your learning rate and find one that will work for various batch sizes and latent dim sizes.